# Prove that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to c} P(x)=P(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, polynomials

I want to prove by definition that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to c} P(x)=P(c)$ when $\displaystyle P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}x^{k}$ to do so, try starting from

$$\left| P(x)-P(c) \right|=\left| \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(x^{k}-c^{k}) \right|=\left| \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(x-c)(x^{k-1}+\dots+c^{k-1}) \right|$$

From where

$$\left| P(x)-P(c) \right|=|x-c|\left| \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(x^{k-1}+\dots+c^{k-1}) \right|$$

It seems that a possible choice of an epsilon could be made, but I don't see it because it should not depend on x. Any suggestions on how to find such an epsilon? I appreciate it!

Comment: For polynomials, it is generally easier to prove $ax^n$ is continous and that the sum of continous functions is continous. Any reason you don't want to take this approach?

Comment: You'll need to bound $x$, provided it's in a neighborhood of $c.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\left| P(x)-P(c) \right|=|x-c|\left| \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(x^{k-1}+\dots+c^{k-1}) \right|$$

First, set $\delta_1=1$, then for all $0<|x-c|<1\Rightarrow |x|\le 1+|c|\Rightarrow|x|^k\le (1+|c|)^k$
$$\left| \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(x^{k-1}+\dots+c^{k-1}) \right|\le  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left| a_{k}(x^{k-1}+\dots+c^{k-1}) \right|\le\sum_{k=0}^{n} | a_{k}|\cdot k\cdot(1+|c|^{k-1})\le M$$

Next, take $\delta=\min(1, \frac{\epsilon}M)$, whenever, $0<|x-c|<\delta$

$$\left| P(x)-P(c) \right|=|x-c|\left| \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}(x^{k-1}+\dots+c^{k-1}) \right|< \epsilon$$

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have only one question, the value of M has some special feature (it is a real, positive integer), what is the intention of choosing M?

Comment: No, there is no special feature, here $M$ only means the finite term sum is bounded by some positive number $M$. Based on this $M$, you can choose your $\delta$

Answer (score 1):

You can change the polynomial basis advantageously to $P(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n b_k(x-c)^k$

This is always possible thanks to the binomial formula, then

$$|P(x)-P(c)|=|P(x)-b_0|\le\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |b_k||x-c|^k$$

Now just take $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon)$ and notice $|u|<1\implies|u|^k<|u|^{k-1}<\cdots<|u|^2<|u|$

Therefore we can simply bound all $|x-c|^k\ $ by $\ |x-c|$ and the sum of the coefficients which is constant.

$$|P(x)-P(c)|\le \underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |b_k|}_\text{cst=M}\times \underbrace{|x-c|\vphantom{\sum\limits_i^i}}_{<\varepsilon}$$

You can eventually refine your delta to take $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{M})$

Comment: See this for my initial claim : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4569136/399263