# Alternative method to proving that $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)+b$ where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials $\in \mathbb R_p[X]$ and $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, real-numbers

An introductory theorem about polynomials (with real coefficients) is the following:

> For any polynomial function $f$ (whose coefficients are in $\mathbb R$) and any number $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, there is a polynomial function $g$ (whose coefficients are in $\mathbb R$) and a number $b \in \mathbb R$ such that: \begin{align}f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)+b\end{align}

The standard proof of this statement (at least from my text book and other submissions on this site) involves proof by induction (e.g. [prove that ,for any polynomial function $f$ ,f can be written as $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)+b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4569100/prove-that-for-any-polynomial-function-f-f-can-be-written-as-fx-x-agx)).

I was too daft in the moment to recall how the proof went, so, instead, I just constructed $g$ with a brute force approach. I looked around to see if my result was replicated elsewhere, but I could not find anything...so I just wanted to make sure that I did not botch my derivation.

---

We aim to prove the statement for an arbitrary $n$-degree polynomial $f(x)=c_n  x^n+\cdots +c_1 x^1+c_0$ and an arbitrary $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.

Consider the two terms: $x\cdot g(x)$ and $\alpha  \cdot g(x)$. Suppose $g(x)$ is an $n-1$-degree polynomial with the following skeletal structure: $g(x)=(K_{n,\alpha})x^{n-1}+(K_{n-1,\alpha})x^{n-2}+\cdots+(K_{3,\alpha})x^2+(K_{2,\alpha})x^1+(K_{1,\alpha})$.

Then, with some purposeful alignment of columns, we can represent $(x-\alpha)g(x)=x\cdot g(x) - \alpha \cdot g(x)$ as:

\begin{alignat}{3}K_{n,\alpha}x^n &+\color{red}{K_{n-1,\alpha}x^{n-1}}+\cdots &&+\color{blue}{K_{2,\alpha}x^2}&&&+\color{green}{K_{1,\alpha}x^1} \\ &-\color{red}{\alpha K_{n,\alpha}x^{n-1}}  - \cdots &&- \color{blue}{\alpha K_{3,\alpha}x^2}&&&-\color{green}{\alpha K_{2,\alpha}x^1}-\alpha K_{1,\alpha}\end{alignat}

Because $b$ is just some number (and, therefore, does not have an $x$ in its expression), in order for this construction to work, we first need to satisfy the following:

$K_{n,\alpha}=c_n$, $K_{n-1,\alpha}-\alpha K_{n,\alpha}=c_{n-1}$, $\cdots$, $K_{2,\alpha}-\alpha K_{3,\alpha}=c_2$, and $K_{1,\alpha}-\alpha K_{2,\alpha}=c_1$.

After some algebra, we can arrive at the following formula for $K_{n-i,\alpha}$.

$$K_{n-i,\alpha}=\sum_{j=0}^i \alpha^{i-j}c_{n-j}$$

Firstly, notice that when $i=0$, $K_{n,\alpha}=c_n$. Next, for any natural number $i$ in $[1,n-1]$, we have that:

\begin{align}K_{n-i,\alpha}-\alpha K_{n-(i-1),\alpha}&=\sum_{j=0}^i \alpha^{i-j}c_{n-j}-\alpha\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\alpha^{(i-1)-j}c_{n-j}\\&=\sum_{j=0}^i \alpha^{i-j}c_{n-j}-\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\alpha^{(i-1)-j+1}c_{n-j}\\&=\left[\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \alpha^{i-j}c_{n-j}-\alpha^{i-j}c_{n-j}\right]+\alpha^0c_{n-i}\\&=c_{n-i}\end{align} as desired.

Finally, we need to address the $-\alpha K_{1,\alpha}$ term that is present in the $(x-\alpha)g(x)$ expansion. Eliminating all terms that involve $x$'s, we see that we need to solve the equation $c_0=-\alpha K_{1,\alpha}+b$. Well...this is trivial and gives us: $b=\alpha K_{1,\alpha}+c_0$. Because $K_{1,\alpha}$ is a defined term not involving $x$, we are done.

Note that these $K$ coefficients are specific to the given $f$ and the given $\alpha$.

Comment: Take $b=f(a)$ and use the fact $x^{k}-a^{k}$ is divisible by $x-a$ for $k\geq 1$.

Comment: You are working much too hard. All you have to do is use the change of variables $y = x - a$ to rewrite $f(x)$ as $f(y + a)$, then expand this out as a polynomial in $y$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am interested in the approach you are suggesting...but I am not quite sure I  understand why this is simpler. It seems like you want me to say: \begin{align}f(x)&=f(y+a)\\&=c_n(y+a)^n+c_{n-1}(y+a)^{n-1}+\cdots+c_2(y+a)^2+c_1(y+a)+c_0 \\ &=c_n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}y^{n-k}a^k+c_{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}y^{(n-1)-k}a^k+\cdots+c_2\sum_{k=0}^{2}\binom{2}{k}y^{2-k}a^k+c_1\sum_{k=0}^{1}y^{1-k}a^k+c_0\end{align}

After expanding all of this, I feel like I will have exerted essentially the same amount of 'brute force' as my original  approach. Am I missing something?

Comment: @S.C.: you don't need to go into that much detail. Just write $f(y + a)$ as a polynomial $\sum d_k y^k$ in $y$, where the $d_k$ are some coefficients that can be written in terms of the coefficients of $f$ but it doesn't particularly matter how. This writes $f(x)$ as a polynomial $\sum d_k (x - a)^k$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ahhh. Sorry, I assumed you were providing an explicit construction of $g$ (where the coefficients are actually known) like I did. I assume your thoughts are: \begin{align}f(x)&=\left[\sum_{k=1}^nd_k(x-a)^k\right]+d_0 \\&=(x-a)\cdot\left[\sum_{k=1}^nd_k(x-a)^{k-1}\right]+d_0 \end{align}

Therefore, $\displaystyle g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nd_k(x-a)^{k-1}$ and $b=d_0$. Thank you for the cool approach. Cheers, Sir~

Comment: Yes, that's it. The problem only asks to show that the polynomial exists. Its coefficients can be described more explicitly in terms of the derivatives of $f$ at $a$, just use the usual Taylor series formula.